# What are the IP/MAC addresses of requests between 2 different subnets?

Tags: routing, router, ip, mac-address, mac

Assume that networks `172.15.10.0/24` and `172.15.11.0/24` are connected through a router with interfaces `172.15.10.254 (MAC3)` and `172.15.11.253 (MAC4)`.

If host A sends a packet through its network interface `172.15.10.1 (MAC1)` to interface `172.15.11.1 (MAC2)`, what's the MAC and IP source and destination addresses of the MAC/IP packets in the two networks?

---

Does the IP/MAC addresses of the initial request correspond to the router or the destination machine?

Comment: Smells like homework, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC addresses are confined to the local network because routers strip the frame off a packet to route the packet to a new network interface. The router then builds a new frame for the protocol on the new interface (remember that not all data-link protocols use MAC addressing).

The IP addresses will remain on the packet from source to destination.